# Javascript continuous typing of string keep item faded in

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dont want to have to write ifs within ifs for every letter of Bill gates typed in a textbox, do i split the letters into an array or what?

```
function callManagers(val){ 
    var val = $("#limitedtextarea").val();
    if (val.indexOf('@BillGates')<=-1) {
        if(val.indexOf('@') > -1) {
            if (val.indexOf('b') > -1 || val.indexOf('B') > -1) {
                $("#test").fadeIn();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want the user to be typing Bill gates and for test to stay faded in so long as they are doing that, but fade out if they type bill gates wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Make sure that the user is typing in "@Bill Gates"?

Comment: @Jayraj Sorry I will try to be more specific, Yeah I want the user to be typing Bill gates and for test to stay faded in so long as they are doing that, but fade out if they type at BillZ

Comment: Just FYI, it's usually healthy to begin a SO question with a general overview of what you're trying to accomplish.  In this case, something like "I have a text area, and I'm trying to watch it for when the user types in '@BillGates' so that I can respond by triggering a fadeIn", before diving in to the details, would probably have been helpful.

Comment: What happens if they type '@BillGates.' (or any other character after the 's')?

Comment: very sorry @machineghost (very long day), that was a perfect way to be the question

Comment: No need to apologize :-)  Just a thought for next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not this?

```
var str = "@BillGates",
    val = $("whatever").val();
if(str.indexOf(val) === 0) { //means val is a substring of "@BillGates"
   //do fade in
}
```

Comment: `illG` would return a positive; you should probably check for the `str.indexOf(val) == 0`

Comment: And the value of `val` is currently `[object Object]` :)

Comment: @Utkanos Lol yes. Just wanted to give a basic idea. Wrote it in a hurry :P